# Print only property names of PowerShell object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to print out only the property names of a Powershell object.
In a script I do an `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Write-Host ($response.result | Format-List | Out-String)` gives me a nice list of the `$response.result` object.
`Get-Member -InputObject $response.result` also does not display what I want.
`$response.result` looks something like this: `@{id=1; skip=true}`.
How do I just get a list/table thats shows `id, skip` etc.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All PowerShell objects have a hidden property `PSObject` that allows accessing information about the object, e.g. its properties:

```
$response.result.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Answer (score 8):

If it's not a hashtable, you can use Get-Member to find the properties like this:

`$response.result | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Select-Object Name`

Answer (score 2):

If the result is just a simple 1-level hashtable, you could do something like:

```
(@{id=1; skip=$true}).GetEnumerator() | %{ $_.Key }

id
skip
```